# How to iterate over an array list in a thread safe manner (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have an array list that I am using in my multi-threaded application, and I want a way to somehow be able to iterate through the array while not causing any exceptions to be thrown when I add a element to the list as I am iterating. Is there a way to stop the array list from being modified while I iterate through it?

Edit:
I now realize that my question was very poorly submitted, and the down votes are deserved. This is an attempt to fix my question.

What I want to do is have some way to 'block' the list before I iterate through it so that I don't get a concurrent modification exception. The issue is that the iterating will take quite a bit of processor time to complete, because the list will be very large, and the action I wish to carry out on each element will take a fair amount of time. This is an issue if I use synchronized methods, because the add method will block for a large amount of time and decrease application performance. So what I am trying to do is create a class that imitates an array list, except that when it is 'blocked', and a method tries to modify it, it will store that request, and when the list is 'unblocked' it will perform all the requests in a separate thread. The issue is that when I try to implement this strategy, I have to store the requests in some sort of list, and run into the same problems I do before, with having to block the ability to add to the request list while the request thread is iterating over the requests. I'm at a loss for how to implement this solution, or even if it is the correct one. if anyone could help me that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use a search engine of your choice to look for: `java synchronized`. But if you don't know about this already, your multi threaded application is going to have a hard time.

Comment: what is your idea or thoughts on approaching it?

Comment: have you tried that ? it should throw a ConcurrentModificationException !

Comment: Conflicting statements: you either want exception during iterations, or you don't. There is no way to prevent modification while "someone, somewhere" is iterating - it will throw ConcurrentMod, but in iterating thread, not modifying thread. If you just want concurrent iteration safe from intermediate modifications, see `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, it may be exactly what you need.

Comment: You can not “iterate over an array list in a thread safe manner” without performing all other operations in a thread safe manner. There are different options, using synchronization for every access to the list makes all threads wait until the iteration is done, a `ReadWriteLock` would allow to have concurrent read access, but might be more complicated to use.

Answer (score 1):

Your options are either to work with synchronization or use implementation provided in package java.util.concurrent. You also need to read up on the issue. you are asking a very fundamental and classical question and there is a LOT of info on this issue.But here are your basic options:

1. Use syncronization - veru expensive performance wise but is absolutely bullet-proof. read up in `synchronized`term or read up on [Lock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) interface and its implementations. Also see about [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) class. Note that this option would create a very serious bottle neck in your performance
2. As one of the comments said use [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) class. Also has some draw backs but in majority of cases is a better option then full synchronization.

When choosing between the 2 options consider the following points: while synchranization is a bullet-proof solution if done right, it is a very tidious work that demands a lot of testing which is not trivial. So this is already a big draw back. Plus in majority of cases reads outnumber writes or Array size is small enough (say up to few hundreds elements) where copy on write is acceptable. So it is my guess that majority of cases CopyOnWriteArrayList would be preferable. The point is that there is no clear cut answer when choosing between the two options above. A programmer needs to look at the circumstances and choose the option that fits his/her case better

Comment: A `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is not “ultimately better option”. Its name already suggests where it has significant costs, which can be dramatically more expensive than “full synchronization”. Besides that, even using `synchronized` is not “bullet-proof”; there is a lot you can do wrong.

Comment: @Holger yes, there is a lot of stuff you can do wrong (in anything as long as you do something) but if you do synchronization right it is bullet-proof. As for CopyOnWriteArrayList it is definitely better option if the number of reads vastly outnumber the number of writes. Also if your Array is not too big. So a programmer needs to look at the circumstances and choose the option that fits his/her case better

Comment: “so a programmer needs to look at the circumstances and choose …” sounds much better than the bold “ultimately better option” statement. You don’t know whether the reads vastly outnumber the writes in the OP’s case.

Comment: Holger - synhcronization is a very tidious work that demands a lot of testing which is not  trivial. So this is already a big draw back. Plus in majority of cases reads outnumber writes or Array size is small enough (say up to few hundreds elements) where copy on write is acceptable. So it is my guess that majority of cases CopyOnWriteArrayList would be preferable.

Comment: It would be better to write such considerations into your answer instead of keeping them in your mind and writing just a sole questionable “ultimately better option” phrase…

Comment: OK, Holger, your advise is good and improves the answer. I updated the answer. Thanks for your helpful comments